# FFmpeg - Fragmented MP4 with non-fixed frame rate

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, mp4, media-source

I'm creating a fragmented MP4 for the use of playing in Media Source Extensions.
The command line is: ffmpeg.exe -probesize 10000000 -r 10 -i - -vcodec copy -an -f mp4 -reset_timestamps 0 -blocksize 30000 -movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof+frag_keyframe -loglevel debug -

The source of the video is an IP camera streaming H.264.
The configured and expected frame rate is 10FPS but there is no guarantee for 10FPS, for example a frame may get dropped occasionally, or the camera may just not play nice with what it declares.
I have simulate a 10% p-frames drops to emphasize the following issue:

With the above command, the output video plays faster than real-time and this is a problem because the whole pipe is a live stream.
With the 10% frame drop simulation, the effective playback rate it 1.1x.
I don't want to obligate to a fixed frame rate because there is no guarantee for a fixed-rate.
If I remove the -r 10 flag entirely, the MP4 seems to the playing at 2x-3x speed.

Is there a way building the MP4 timestamps in a more dynamic way? for example, giving it the RTP timestamp or somehow telling ffmpeg to build the MP4 with the timestamp of the "feed" time?